# Root mean square error of bearings

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have two sets of bearing angle data, one is forecast and the other one is actual, i.e.

```
forecast = {80, 270, 355, 40, 58, 290, 5}
actual = {85, 5, 10, 90, 70, 10, 20}
```

How can I calculate the root mean square error between the two sets?

Comment: `RootMeanSquare[forecast - actual]` or `Sqrt[Mean[(forecast - actual)^2]]`

Comment: 80 compared to 85 makes sense but the other points are way off? Is this intentional?

Comment: Not really, the forecast sometimes go wrong.  As they are bearing angles, the calculation cannot not simply be "forecast - actual".  For example, the 3rd pair of data {355, 10}, difference is 15 deg only instead of (355-10) = 345 deg.

Comment: Please edit this "compass" information into the post instead of the comments.

Comment: `RootMeanSquare[Min[Mod[#, 360], Mod[-#, 360]] &  /@ (forecast - actual)]`  gives `4 Sqrt[1159/7]`, about 51 degrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
forecast = {80, 270, 355, 40, 58, 290, 5} 
actual = {85, 5, 10, 90, 70, 10, 20}
```

Mathematica requires the symbol `Degree` to denote angles in degrees as trig functions use radians.

---

Define a utility function:

```
DegreesBW[x1_, x2_] := 
 VectorAngle[{Cos[x1], Sin[x1]}, {Cos[x2], Sin[x2]}]*180/\[Pi] // N
```

Typical usage:

```
DegreesBW[1, -1]  (* 114.592, or 2 radians *)

DegreesBW[1 Degree, -1 Degree]   (* 2. *)
```

---

**Application**

I have to multiply both of the input lists by `Degree` as shown below or else the given values will be treated as radians .

```
err = MapThread[DegreesBW, Degree {forecast, actual}]
```

> {5., 95., 15., 50., 12., 80., 15.}

```
RootMeanSquare[err]
```

> 51.4698